# How to make tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I am making a database about cars going around a certain street. So I made a table that keep the information of the CarId and the date when the car passed the particular street. The car can pass the street millions time, I know I need to make another table for that to keep all the dates but I am confused. Please help. How the database should look like

Comment: You need a "one to many" or 1:n relation Model. Check out this: http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/

Comment: OK, now think of the *objects* (entities) that you what to keep track of - cars? Streets? Those tends to become tables in your database model. What **attributes** about those entities do you need to keep track of - colors of the car? Manufacturer? Make? Size? What else? Those will be the **columns** of your database tables. How are those entities related to one another ??

Comment: Get yourself a **good book** on the basics of database design - e.g. Mike Hernandez' [Database Design for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0321884493/) and learn this stuff. This is **way too broad** to be answered in a single SO question .....

Comment: I don't need to keep track of the street. I have 10 cars with ID 1 to 10 . I need to keep track at the time and date when they go in Manhattan for  example. So I make a database to keep my cars. And what about the other table that will keep the information of all the date and time the car has gone in Manhattan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what database you're using, I'm going to assume MS SQL Server / SQL Express. The following SQL should fulfil your requirements

```
-- Stores details about individual cars
create table Car
(
  ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
  Registration varchar(10),
  Make varchar(20),
  Model varchar(50)
  -- Add any other fields here
)
go

-- Stores details about each time a "known" car passes by the location
create table Sightings
(
  ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
  CarID int not null,
  constraint Sightings_FK_Car foreign key (CarID) references Car (ID),
  SightedAt datetime not null
  -- Add any other fields here
)
```

Using meaningless integers as primary keys on the tables is a matter of personal preference. You could use something like the registration number of the car as the primary key on the first table and a combination of the car registration and time of sighting on the second. I prefer the meaningless integer for performance reasons.

Comment: You should name your primary keys with the table prefix, i.e. `CarID` and `SightingsID` so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much.But here is what I need. So a car goes in Manhattan at 1 pm 12/12/12 . And I need to store the car and the date . The car can go to Manhattent 10000 times. How to store this? the car model or anything it does not matter . I am making tables manually in sql server

Comment: @Elliot - normally I'd define a PK as "constraint Car_PK primary key (ID)", but I was going for brevity here ;)

Comment: @Besa - google is your friend. search for "SQL INSERT INTO" to figure out the syntax for adding records to the tables. You'll need to insert a single record for each car in the Car table, and a record into sightings each time a car passes by your location.